# Linux library monitoring tool wanted

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I need to know which applications use the library `xxx.so` .

I know the command `ldd`. But that's not what I looking for.

A tool which tell me something like

> app1 and app2 using xxx.so

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is not applications, but [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) which are using files.

You could use the [lsof](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_lsof.htm) command to find out which processes are accessing or using some given file.

You might also be interested by the `pmap` command, and the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page (about the `/proc/` file system), e.g. `/proc/1234/maps`and `/proc/1234/fd/` for the process of pid 1234.

Notice that static libraries are not really used, but linked (i.e. "mixed") inside an executable (at build time).

You might also be interested in packages dependencies. Details vary with your Linux distributions (e.g. `.deb` based or `.rpm` based packages).